# Opening document from dialogbox

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a button in which I open a dialogbox. In this dialogbox I show a Form in which I have an embedded view. Is it possible when I double click a button that it opens the document in that dialogbox??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible. Dialog boxes in Notes client are **modal**.

You can open another dialog box from a dialog box though. There you could show a document. But, it's not the same as opening a document.

It might be better if you open the document with the Form instead showing it in a dialog box.

Comment: thanks how can i open the form, if i double click it an element it does nothing

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the embedded editor feature to do this. I.e., in addition to the embedded view, you embed an editor. You set the embedded editor as the target for the embedded view.  This process described in this [IBM Lotus documentation page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_EMBEDDED_EDITORS_OVER.html). The only question is whether this works when the embedded view and embedded editor are in a dialog box. I can't think of a reason why that wouldn't work, but I don't recall ever trying it in a dialog box so I'm not sure.